# Cannot create Visual Studio 2012 MVC4 WebAPI project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have installed visual studio 2012 ultimate. I tried to create new project - MVC4 - WebAPI. I got the error message **"The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070002)"**

I have reinstalled vs 2012 and repair mode also. I still cannot rid of this error message.

Any advise?

Comment: Do you have any previous version of VS in your computer? I had the same problem and solved it uninstalling older versions of MVC components. After that, repaired VS 2012.

Comment: Yes I have. Ok I will do what you have done. I tried uninstall vs2012 and re-installed. It didn't work. I will remove all MVC related and repaire 2012. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Download ASP.NET Web tools 2012.2 from

http://www.asp.net/downloads and install it

I am quite positive you should be able to create ASP.NET MVC projects using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention install ASP.NET web tools 2012.2